# How to Scroll to top of page

Tags: development

I have a webpart that contains asp classic code, this code resides on a different domain. I would like to be able that anytime that anything happens in the webpart, the main page will refresh to the top of the page.

Could anyone give me any suggestions?

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Is the webpart in SharePoint? Is it rendering an iframe with the "asp classic code from a different domain"?

Answer (score 0):

When you update the webpart using either server side or client side. You could set the page scroll to the top using following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(this).scrollTop(0);
});
```